# Android map how to draw Parallel Lines with some distance

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

For example draw Parallel Lines line with some distance

Comment: what is your requirement ?? where is your description?

Comment: My requirement  is draw Parallel Lines with same point in some distance

Comment: so you can draw the red line ? what data you have  to draw the red line ?

Comment: yes red and blue both parallel line with location change then how to draw lines ?

Comment: do you have latlng for red line ?
do you have latlng for blue line ?

Comment: both latlng on location changed Listener

Comment: please be specific to the question . do you have latlng for red line ? do you have latlng for blue line ?

Comment: Both latlng same for both line but some distance to draw line

Comment: ok so you have latlng for blue line and latlng for red line . right ? you can draw them independently . right ?